# Komodo Edit auto complete

Tags: text-editors, komodo-edit

I am just starting to use Komodo Edit. I have linked to a few CSS files but when I am editing an HTML file and then add a class to an element I would like the editor to guess what I am typing by referencing styles in my style sheets.

Can this be done? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure Komodo (IDE nor Edit) doesn't support this.  There's been a long standing bug/feature request for CSS hinting:

https://bugs.activestate.com/show_bug.cgi?id=90981